# UFT Script execution in Browser window slow

Tags: hp-uft

UFT take 5-6 minutes to to click a HTML WebElement link , Web Element is configured with css path.

Browser: iexplorer 11.2; UFT 14.01

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Browser Zoom. When set to anything other than 100%, the script will revert to using smart identification which takes longer to recognise.

IE browser Zoom can be reset to 100% using send keys:

```
Dim mySendKeys
set mySendKeys = CreateObject("WScript.shell")
mySendKeys.SendKeys("^0")  ' the ^ means ctrl in sendkey method
```

Source: https://community.softwaregrp.com/t5/Unified-Functional-Testing-User/Configuring-browser-s-visibility-BEFORE-it-is-launched/td-p/1636797

Comment: Even with smart identification 5.6 minutes sounds like an extremely long time. The point is good if a test is slow look in the report to see if smart identification was used.